# ¿Como meter un selector dentro de un data list?

Tags: javascript, html5, datalist

estoy intentando hacer un input/datalist cuyas opciones sean selectores o desplegables.

Referencia[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, es un datalist con desplegables dentro.

¿Cómo se hace eso?, agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Podría intentar configurar una solución usando el tag [`optgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvsndcmb/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Optgroup</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<select>
  <optgroup label="Opciones 1">
    <option>Opción 1A</option>
    <option>Opción 1B</option>
    <option>Opción 1C</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Opciones 2">
    <option>Opción 2A</option>
    <option>Opción 2B</option>
    <option>Opción 2C</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Si no, ¿podría agregar el link a la página que desea jugar?

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)

Comment: Gracias, Matt! Eres muy amable al responder, tu sugerencia me ayuda en algo pero no solventa en sí el problema, te dejo la referencia para darme a entender mejor. https://awake.travel/es/home checa el buscador como tiene desplegables dentro de las opciones

Comment: @BrianAlexander Muy interesante! Esto no es un `datalist`, un script JS genera un tag `input`. `datalist` no hace todas estas cosas (opciones anidadas y links) :(